# Transform list of dictionaries into dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

I have a list of dictionaries with identical keys. Furthermore, there are only two 'key: value' pairs per dictionary. I want to convert the list of dictionaries to a single dictionary with two keys, each representing a list value. Such that values of identical keys reside in one list.

I came up with the following approach, which by the way works perfectly fine. But I am hoping to know if there is any better practical approach.

**The List of Dictionaries:**

```py
my_list = [{'old_price': None, 'price': '5,75'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '5,90'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '5,95'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '10,15'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '19,90'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '34,90'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '46,50'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '24,90'}]
```

**List of Dictionaries to Dictionary of Lists:**

```py
single_dict = {"old_price": [item['old_price'] for item in my_list], "price":[item['price'] for item in my_list]}
```

**The Resulted Dictionary:**

```
{'old_price': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], 'price': ['5,75', '5,90', '5,95', '10,15', '19,90', '34,90', '46,50', '24,90']}
```

Comment: Is this post help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-taking-union-of-dictiona

Comment: What don't you like about your solution? To me it looks like it's good

Comment: @CyrillePontvieux Do any of the answers there show how to make a list of all the values from the dictionaries? It looks like they just overwrite the common keys.

Comment: @barmar that answer OP question: how to merge multiple dictionaries into one ; not how to extract only value, but the solution is almost the same, just use a set or list instead of a dict when iterating/deconstruct

Comment: I checked the post but it doesn't seem to work for me. @CyrillePontvieux

Answer (score 0):

With the use of [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), you can make the algorithm *O(N)*, looping over the list one single time.

```py
>>> my_list = [{'old_price': None, 'price': '5,75'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '5,90'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '5,95'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '10,15'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '19,90'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '34,90'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '46,50'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '24,90'}]

>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)  # will create a list for every missing entry
>>> for adict in my_list:
...    for key, value in adict.items():
...       d[key].append(value)
...    
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'old_price': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], 'price': ['5,75', '5,90', '5,95', '10,15', '19,90', '34,90', '46,50', '24,90']})
```

If you know beforehand the keys that you need, you can swap the loop with fixed assignments (however the time cost is very small):

```py
>>> for adict in my_list:
...    d["old_price"].append(adict["old_price"])
...    d["price"].append(adict["price"])
...
```

Comment: *"With the use of `defaultdict`, you can make the algorithm O(N)"*. I love `defaultdict`, but it's not magic, and doesn't really "make" anything O(N). In fact, the solution suggested by the OP in their question is already O(N).

Comment: It's not magic, but if a key is missing you will have a default "blank" element. The algorithm proposed by OP is O(N*M), where M is the number of keys extracted from the small dictionaries - in this case M=2.

Comment: And you're claiming that your code is **not** O(N*M)?

Comment: The first version provided is indeed O(N*M); however this is not true for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate to your `dict` and then create a new dict with a checker whether is already created or not.

```
my_list = [{'old_price': None, 'price': '5,75'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '5,90'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '5,95'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '10,15'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '19,90'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '34,90'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '46,50'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '24,90'}]
result = {}
for each_dict in my_list:
    for k in each_dict:
        if (k in result): 
            result[k].append(each_dict[k])
        else:
            result[k] = [each_dict[k]]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'old_price': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], 'price': ['5,75', '5,90', '5,95', '10,15', '19,90', '34,90', '46,50', '24,90']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Processing data, I am used to using pandas...

```
import pandas as pd

my_list = [{'old_price': None, 'price': '5,75'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '5,90'},
           {'old_price': None, 'price': '5,95'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '10,15'},
           {'old_price': None, 'price': '19,90'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '34,90'},
           {'old_price': None, 'price': '46,50'}, {'old_price': None, 'price': '24,90'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)

columns = df.columns.tolist()
data = {}
// merge same key
for key in columns:
    data[key] = df[key].tolist()

print(data)
```

Comment: I'm looking for a practice with pure python only, not using pandas.

Comment: @UğurEren--you should add this constraint to the question rather than comment where it is buried.  T

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
values = list(map(list, zip(*[item.values() for item in my_list])))
single_dict = { 'old_price':values[0], 'price':values[1] }
```